# How can I restructure this data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to change:

| Name | Year | Number of Visits |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 2019 | 2 |
| Bob | 2020 | 3 |
| Sam | 2019 | 4 |
| Sam | 2020 | 1 |

To:

| Name | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 2 | 3 |
| Sam | 4 | 1 |

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider()` should be useful for your purposes.

Comment: More generally called "converting from long to wide" formats. Quite a few approaches to doing this in R.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `xtabs`

```
xtabs(NumberofVisits ~ Name + Year, df1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)

# Sample data.
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      Name = c("Bob", "Bob", "Sam", "Sam"),
      Year = c(2019,
               2020, 2019, 2020),
      Number.of.Visits = c(2, 3, 4, 1)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,
                  -4L))

df %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = Number.of.Visits)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Name  `2019` `2020`
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Bob        2      3
2 Sam        4      1
```